# How to link two pre-existing and non-empty directories through Git?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, collaboration

I am collaborating on a project with a friend. We have two different file structures but we are sharing the same few files, like below:

Me:

```
Root ->
    Folder_A ->
        File 1a
        File 2a
    Folder B ->
        File 1b
        File 2b
```

Him:

```
Root ->
    Folder_A ->
        File 1a
        File 2a
        File 3a
    Folder B (Called something else) ->
        File 1b
        File 2b
    Folder C ->
        File 1c
```

The final repository should only contain:

```
Root ->
    Folder A->
        File 1a
    Folder B->
        File 2b
```

In this example, we only need to share folders 1a and 2b. Every file is already created on our  local systems, respectively.
You can see that he has other files that can't be touched like Folder C and File 1c.

How do I set up a repository that only captures these few files that we need and ignores everything else on both of our systems?

I know about .gitignore, the problem is that both of our directories are already non-empty. I don't know how to sync just the files we need and ignore everything else in these directories. This is made more difficult since his folders are called different names.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "our directories are already non-empty"? I don't see any problem with using `.gitignore`. You can remove your cached files and commit the changes.

Comment: Git itself stores—inside commits— *only* files; the files just have names that imply, to your OS at least, that there should be some folder. That is, Git might store a *file* named `path/to/file`. That's not a folder `path` holding a folder `to` holding a file named `file`, it's a file whose name is literally `path/to/file`, complete with the embedded forward slashes. It's important to keep in mind that what's in a Git commit *isn't* what you see and edit in files stored in folders on your computer. Those files-in-folders are just how you get Git to *create* the Git versions.

Comment: Hence, if you want to get Git to store, in the next commit, a file named `Folder_A/file 1a`, you would run `git add "Folder_A/file 1a"` (the quotes here are often necessary to protect the spaces in the names, which don't play well with Unix-like systems). This makes Git look up that path name on your OS (which treats these as folder-and-file) and then create or update, in Git's *index* aka *staging area*, the file with the name with the embedded forward slash.

Comment: Your next `git commit` takes all the files that are in Git's index—the staging area—and makes a commit from them. The index/staging-area is actually the reason that Git can't store empty folders: the index format has no way to do that. (There's something that comes very close, but Git mangles it now and then if you attempt to use it that way.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no remote repo, first you and then your friend basically need to follow [this steps](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line). In step 5, you first add your `file 1a` (the folder will be added automatically, no need for ignoring anything else). After you push, your friend can clone the repo and add his `file 2b` respectively.